# Assistance to receive my money

Tags: private-key

Pls, someone introduce Bitcoin mining to me, that I will be receiving 50% of money invested after 6hrs. He has me to pay him in order to fund my wallet. I transfer money to him,  he ask for my wallet ID and password. I refuse in the first instance but he said he want to connect my wallet to mining. The password was released. He funded the account. It reaches 7-8 hrs I didn't see any increase in my balance till the following day. I now decided to withdraw my money back. It then I noticed that there is imported Bitcoin address requesting for private key. I later click on menu to click on addresses  ,I saw archived address again...
Pls, what can I do to  receive my money?
I have changed my password. And I have my recovery phrase with me.
How can I remove imported address and private key. And the archive Bitcoin address.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you give someone your bitcoin login which is the worse thing you can do. Unless you know that person and can really be trusted, this could be a type of scam. Try to withdraw all your money and if you can't mean he got all your money.

Never invest with random peoples/website <= A very very high risk

Comment: By the way, your question and information that you provided me were unclear so this is what I can do for you.

Please put what type of wallet company are you using so we can provide you more detail

Comment: Btw he did lie to you, bitcoin mining is when you solve hashes and earn the profit based on how much your hash is (pool mining)

Answer (score 1):

This is a scam, withdraw your coins from that wallet and never use that wallet again!

Changing your password is not sufficient to protect your account at this point. If the scammer can log in to your wallet they can copy down the recovery seed phrase, and then recreate your wallet using other software. The password only protects your login, it would not stop the scammer from accessing your wallet using a different platform.

Mining requires specialized hardware, the scammer lied in saying he would 'set your account up to mine'. That is not how mining works.

Sorry for your losses. In the future do not EVER give your account info, passwords, seed phrases, private keys, etc, to anyone that you do not trust 100%.